# React Form with subtotals

Tags: reactjs

I worked wth AG-Grid but not sure we can achieve a design like following. I tried but no luck.

Could someone help me to develop a form with subtotals? I know we have a Pivot library but we cannot achieve a design like the following. Could someone please help whether any library exists or some basic idea of how to develop a form like this?

Please note we need filters and sorting,  as AG-Grid provides it by default on top.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Materias-ui Tables. They are incredibly versatile and easy to use because of good documentation and examples on the official website.

Therefore, I can see that your desired result can be achieved with **Collapsible table** and **Sorting & selecting**. Although I suggest you read the whole page.

https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table